transformation of matrix equation $ \mathbf{y} =\mathbf{B} \mathbf{f}-\overline{\mathbf{B}} \mathbf{C} \mathbf{f}$
I found this transformation in a paper about image reconstruction:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{y} & =\mathbf{B} \mathbf{f}-\overline{\mathbf{B}} \mathbf{C} \mathbf{f}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbf{B} & -\overline{\mathbf{B}}
\end{array}\right]\left(\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
\mathbf{c}
\end{array}\right] \otimes \mathbf{f}\right) \\
& =\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{b} \otimes \mathbf{f}) \\
& =\mathbf{H} \operatorname{vec}\left(\mathbf{f b}^{\top}\right)=\mathbf{H} \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf{F})
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$ , $\overline{\mathbf{B}}=\left[\mathbf{B}_1, \mathbf{B}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{B}_J\right],  \mathbf{C}=\mathbf{c} \otimes \mathbf{I}_N, \mathbf{c}=\left[c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_J\right]^{\top}$,
$ \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^M, \mathbf{f} \in \mathbb{R}^N $
I don't understand this equation transformation. Could you help fill in the gaps?
$\mathbf{I}_N$ is $N \times N $ identity matrix.
$\mathbf{H}$, $\mathbf{b}$ are matrices or vectors appeared within the transformations without any annotation.
